# How to open page in new window and not in same window and on its new tab?

Tags: javascript, jsp, post, window

When user click a button in main page, My page open in same window as new tab and not open a new window or popup window. Below is my code :

```
  var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "popupPage.jsp");

    form.setAttribute("target", "view");

    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input"); 
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "message");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", "val");
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    document.body.appendChild(form); 
    window.open('', 'view'); 
    form.submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Give some **dimension** to the window ie **height and width** and also instead of **'view'** give **'_blank'**.For Example:

```
window.open('','_blank','width=400, height=400");
```

We will get **two windows** opened,one opened by window.open() and another will open due to form.submit().
So, **remove** the form.submit() line and format the data in 'parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2' using following code:

```
  var elements = form.elements;
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     if (elements[i].name.length) {
         data.push(elements[i].name + "=" + elements[i].value);
     }
   }
var myWindow = window.open('popupPage.jsp', '_blank','width=400, height=400'); 
myWindow.data =data.join('&');
```

Comment: //other code
    window.open('', '_blank'); 
    form.submit(); I tried this, It opens a new popup window containing popuppage.jsp at the same time open a blank tab in current window

Comment: So you are saying you are getting two windows?Then, one is due to window.open() another is due to form.submit()

Comment: I try to remove the window.open() line and change target of form to '_blank' but the window opens in new tab at the same window. @ankit chaudhary

Comment: could you use window.open() instead of form.submit()?

Comment: My problem on using window.open is request parameter are included on the address bar ,like this Page.html?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2 so I try to work on form submit so parameter values can be passed without appending it to address bar.

Comment: If the parent window and the popup are from the same domain,then you can set data to the window itself like this:                 var myWindow = window.open('popupPage.jsp', '_blank','width=400, height=400');
myWindow.data = <yourDataToBePassed>;

Comment: can you give me sample format on how to get from `Page.html?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2` to  myWindow.data = <yourDataToBePassed>;

Comment: added the sample...hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
    myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
```